# Laravel: Redirect to login after session has expired on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

If I log in to my web app, wait for the session to expire, then make an ajax request with a form in my web app I get the following error show up in the console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Ideally what would happen is a redirect to the login page or an error message shows up under the form that fired the ajax request (i.e. something meaningful to the user). It may be worth noting I already have the client side code to throw up errors to show an error message to the user if they make a validation error on the form.

I believe I have an idea how to check if the session is expired and return something useful to the user telling them to login but I'm unsure how I'd implement this globally. So I'm wondering is it possible to handle this issue globally from the back end in Laravel and (or) do I need to write some logic for each ajax request to catch the issue to show an error message client side?

I'm using Laravel and Javascript/JQuery. Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: As above, followed by a question mark: "So I'm wondering is it possible to handle this issue globally from the back end in Laravel and (or) do I need to write some logic for each ajax request to catch the issue to show an error message client side?" - this is not meant to be sarcastic - thanks. Perhaps it's not specific enough - Apologies.

Comment: @haakym if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it yet, I'll be sure to feed back as soon as I have done. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the quick solution for your case:

**Controller** (e.g. AuthController.php):

```
/**
 * Check user session.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function checkSession()
{
    return Response::json(['guest' => Auth::guest()]);
}
```

Also, probably it will be needed to add this method name to ignore by `guest` middleware:

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'checkSession']]);
```

**Route**:

```
Route::get('check-session', 'Auth\AuthController@checkSession');
```

**Layout** (JS part), only for signed in users:

```
@if (Auth::user())
  <script>
    $(function() {
      setInterval(function checkSession() {
        $.get('/check-session', function(data) {
          // if session was expired
          if (data.guest) {
            // redirect to login page
            // location.assign('/auth/login');

            // or, may be better, just reload page
            location.reload();
          }
        });
      }, 60000); // every minute
    });
  </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

use *Middleware*

**Middleware:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class OldMiddleware {

    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       if(!**condition to check login**)
       {
         // if session is expired
          return response()->json(['message' => 'Forbidden!'],403);
       }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => '\App\Http\Middleware\OldMiddleware'], function(){
    //put the routes which needs authentication to complete
});
```

**View:**

```
$.ajax({

     type: 'post',
     url: {{route('someroute')}}
    //etc etc

}).done(function(data){
    //do if request succeeds
}).fail(function(x,y,z){
    //show error message or redirect since it is failed.
});
```